# Convert List<object> to a class

Tags: c#, linq

I have three class :

```
public class MyClass
{
    public Head Head { get; set; }

    public List<Car> Cars { get; set; }
}

public class Head
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Car
{
    public string Color { get; set; }

    public bool Active { get; set; }
}
```

And one instance `List<object>` :

```
List<object> o = new List<object>()
{
    new Head()
    {
        Id = 1
    },
    new Car()
    {
        Color = "Yellow",
        Active = false
    },
    new Car()
    {
        Color = "Black",
        Active = true
    },
    new Car()
    {
        Color = "White",
        Active = false
    }
};
```

I want to convert my instance to a instance of my class `MyClass` (first index = property Head of my class `MyClass` and all Car = property List)

What is the best way to do this ?

Comment: Try this :             MyClass myClass = new MyClass()
            {
                Head = (Head)o.Take(1),
                Cars = o.Skip(1).Select(x => (Car)x).ToList()
            };  Artiom solution doesn't skip first item to get cars.

Comment: In Artiom solution, the first item is type of Head so it is not taken

Answer (score 4):

Linq will help you here.
Use [OfType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method to get instances of certain type.

```
new MyClass{
   Head = o.OfType<Head>().First(),
   Cars = o.OfType<Car>().ToList()
}
```